# how to show image in "data:image" format in another tab

Tags: javascript, image

I have this tag:

```
<img src="data:image;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gAoT3B0..." onclick="window.open($(this).attr('src'), '_blank');" />
```

I wanna to show that image in a new tab when i click on it but it show characters instead of image in new tab

how can i resolve this?

Comment: I use ASP.NET MVC 5.0

Comment: The `src` of `<img>` at Question is not a valid `data URI`

Comment: @guest271314 I dont write complete Uri because it was very long

Comment: Actually, the `data URI` at `src` of `<img>` at Question is a valid `data URI`, though the `MIME` type will default to `"text/plain"` without specifying a valid image `MIME` type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `data URI` at `<img>` element `src` at Question is missing complete `MIME` type

```
data:image;
```

e.g., `"image/jpeg"`

> ```
> data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>
> ```
>
> The mediatype is a MIME type string, such as 'image/jpeg' for a JPEG
>   image file. **If omitted, defaults to text/plain;charset=US-ASCII**

Comment: [Data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) , plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/mP7rsbZWFd8U7luLxfrR?p=preview

Comment: thanks a lot ,it worked ... but problem is that format of image is not fixed and cause of this i didnt set it in src

Answer (score 0):

My Dear Friend ....
You can Use an asp MVC Action which returns  File Result , so you need just type Url link in Href Attribute  and it will open Image in New Windows for you...
Here is an example which I used In My Project

```
  [HttpGet]
    [Route("ShowDoc/{TicketDocId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ShowDoc(long TicketDocId)
    {
        JObject obj = ClsServer.MakeCommonRequestByMobile();
        JObject tJobject = new JObject();
        tJobject["TicketDocId"] = TicketDocId;
        obj["data"] = tJobject;

        var Result = await ClsServer.PostRequestWithResponseData<ServiceResponse>("Ticket/GetDoc", obj);
        return File(Result.Data.Map<Vm_TicketDoc>().Doc, "image/jpg");
    }
```

Result.Data.Map().Doc returns An binary Image stored in Database

Comment: Good idea...But it needs more Changes in code ,thanks